# MongoDB huge bulk insert performance

Tags: performance, mongodb

I'm inserting a lot of data e.g. 1 mln documents. How should I insert them? After small tests I have a different time results for inserting all data in arrays of 500 and 1000 size (bulk). In my use case 500 is faster. Which buffer size should I use? Any suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't an exact formula for that. Too many variables play here. You may use a good compromise value (after tests on different machines) or an adaptive value (1st chunk 500, 2nd 1000, 3rd 2000) timing performance and using that value for subsequent calls (even storing that in configuration, maybe).

Comment: I have observed Javascript's behavior while bulk adding the documents to mongodb. Not saying that it **is** the right answer, but javascript code was probably adding 200 docs per attempt.

Answer (score 1):

For batch inserts like the one you are talking about it would be better to use the appropriately named [`mongoimport` command line tool](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

> The mongoimport tool provides a route to import content from a JSON, CSV, or TSV export created by mongoexport, or potentially, another third-party export tool...